# Openstack Autopilot - Can't attach volume to an instance

Tags: juju, openstack, openstack-autopilot

I have managed to deploy Openstack on 6 machines using Landscape Autopilot. I can create instances (without volume) and other things.

It seems works well until I try to attach volume to an instance through Horizon or Openstack client CLI. It always failed. In Horizon, there are no error messages.

Similar problem happens when I try to create an instance with 'Create new volume' enabled (in Horizon). In this case, there was an error message said:

```
"Error: Failed to perform requested operation on instance "xxxxxx" the instance has an error status: Please try again later [Error: No valid host was found. There are not enough hosts available]"
```

For additional informations I was using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, MAAS version 2.1.3, Juju version 2.1.2 and conjure-up as tools to deploy Openstack.

Please help me. It has been 1 month since I managed to deploy Openstack, this problem has not been solved at all.

**Updated** 
here is nova-compute.log (the one that showed up when I tried to attach volume to an instance)

```
2017-05-12 02:58:00.534 14474 WARNING oslo.privsep.daemon [-] privsep log: Option "logdir" from group "DEFAULT" is deprecated. Use option "log-dir" from group "DEFAULT".
2017-05-12 02:58:00.535 14474 WARNING oslo.privsep.daemon [-] privsep log: Option "verbose" from group "DEFAULT" is deprecated for removal.  Its value may be silently ignored in the future.
2017-05-12 02:58:00.862 14474 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver [req-15a58e2b-017b-4104-b156-d6ddb45727ab ae67e9e8fc51406fb890389fd06e44af 18483cc44c884278b94bf3bb41421175 - - -] [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63] Failed to attach volume at mountpoint: /dev/vdb
2017-05-12 02:58:00.862 14474 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63] Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-05-12 02:58:00.862 14474 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 1232, in attach_volume
2017-05-12 02:58:00.862 14474 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]     guest.attach_device(conf, persistent=True, live=live)
2017-05-12 02:58:00.862 14474 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/guest.py", line 304, in attach_device
2017-05-12 02:58:00.862 14474 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]     device_xml = conf.to_xml()
2017-05-12 02:58:00.862 14474 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/config.py", line 77, in to_xml
2017-05-12 02:58:00.862 14474 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]     root = self.format_dom()
2017-05-12 02:58:00.862 14474 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/config.py", line 765, in format_dom
2017-05-12 02:58:00.862 14474 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]     uuid=self.auth_secret_uuid))
2017-05-12 02:58:00.862 14474 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 2998, in lxml.etree.Element (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:80607)
2017-05-12 02:58:00.862 14474 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 135, in lxml.etree._makeElement (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:17604)
2017-05-12 02:58:00.862 14474 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 123, in lxml.etree._makeElement (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:17452)
2017-05-12 02:58:00.862 14474 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 302, in lxml.etree._initNodeAttributes (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:19840)
2017-05-12 02:58:00.862 14474 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 316, in lxml.etree._addAttributeToNode (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:20196)
2017-05-12 02:58:00.862 14474 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 1437, in lxml.etree._utf8 (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:32414)
2017-05-12 02:58:00.862 14474 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63] TypeError: Argument must be bytes or unicode, got 'NoneType'
2017-05-12 02:58:00.862 14474 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]
2017-05-12 02:58:00.918 14474 ERROR nova.virt.block_device [req-15a58e2b-017b-4104-b156-d6ddb45727ab ae67e9e8fc51406fb890389fd06e44af 18483cc44c884278b94bf3bb41421175 - - -] [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63] Driver failed to attach volume 033dd195-e032-4551-91f4-af7e0c23b388 at /dev/vdb
2017-05-12 02:58:00.918 14474 ERROR nova.virt.block_device [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63] Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-05-12 02:58:00.918 14474 ERROR nova.virt.block_device [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/block_device.py", line 273, in attach
2017-05-12 02:58:00.918 14474 ERROR nova.virt.block_device [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]     device_type=self['device_type'], encryption=encryption)
2017-05-12 02:58:00.918 14474 ERROR nova.virt.block_device [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 1243, in attach_volume
2017-05-12 02:58:00.918 14474 ERROR nova.virt.block_device [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]     self._disconnect_volume(connection_info, disk_dev)
2017-05-12 02:58:00.918 14474 ERROR nova.virt.block_device [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 220, in __exit__
2017-05-12 02:58:00.918 14474 ERROR nova.virt.block_device [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]     self.force_reraise()
2017-05-12 02:58:00.918 14474 ERROR nova.virt.block_device [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 196, in force_reraise
2017-05-12 02:58:00.918 14474 ERROR nova.virt.block_device [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]     six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb)
2017-05-12 02:58:00.918 14474 ERROR nova.virt.block_device [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 1232, in attach_volume
2017-05-12 02:58:00.918 14474 ERROR nova.virt.block_device [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]     guest.attach_device(conf, persistent=True, live=live)
2017-05-12 02:58:00.918 14474 ERROR nova.virt.block_device [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/guest.py", line 304, in attach_device
2017-05-12 02:58:00.918 14474 ERROR nova.virt.block_device [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]     device_xml = conf.to_xml()
2017-05-12 02:58:00.918 14474 ERROR nova.virt.block_device [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/config.py", line 77, in to_xml
2017-05-12 02:58:00.918 14474 ERROR nova.virt.block_device [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]     root = self.format_dom()
2017-05-12 02:58:00.918 14474 ERROR nova.virt.block_device [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/config.py", line 765, in format_dom
2017-05-12 02:58:00.918 14474 ERROR nova.virt.block_device [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]     uuid=self.auth_secret_uuid))
2017-05-12 02:58:00.918 14474 ERROR nova.virt.block_device [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 2998, in lxml.etree.Element (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:80607)
2017-05-12 02:58:00.918 14474 ERROR nova.virt.block_device [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 135, in lxml.etree._makeElement (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:17604)
2017-05-12 02:58:00.918 14474 ERROR nova.virt.block_device [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 123, in lxml.etree._makeElement (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:17452)
2017-05-12 02:58:00.918 14474 ERROR nova.virt.block_device [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 302, in lxml.etree._initNodeAttributes (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:19840)
2017-05-12 02:58:00.918 14474 ERROR nova.virt.block_device [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 316, in lxml.etree._addAttributeToNode (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:20196)
2017-05-12 02:58:00.918 14474 ERROR nova.virt.block_device [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 1437, in lxml.etree._utf8 (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:32414)
2017-05-12 02:58:00.918 14474 ERROR nova.virt.block_device [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63] TypeError: Argument must be bytes or unicode, got 'NoneType'
2017-05-12 02:58:00.918 14474 ERROR nova.virt.block_device [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [req-15a58e2b-017b-4104-b156-d6ddb45727ab ae67e9e8fc51406fb890389fd06e44af 18483cc44c884278b94bf3bb41421175 - - -] [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63] Failed to attach 033dd195-e032-4551-91f4-af7e0c23b388 at /dev/vdb
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63] Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 4788, in _attach_volume
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]     do_check_attach=False, do_driver_attach=True)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/block_device.py", line 48, in wrapped
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]     ret_val = method(obj, context, *args, **kwargs)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/block_device.py", line 282, in attach
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]     connector)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 220, in __exit__
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]     self.force_reraise()
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 196, in force_reraise
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]     six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/block_device.py", line 273, in attach
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]     device_type=self['device_type'], encryption=encryption)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 1243, in attach_volume
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]     self._disconnect_volume(connection_info, disk_dev)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 220, in __exit__
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]     self.force_reraise()
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 196, in force_reraise
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]     six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 1232, in attach_volume
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]     guest.attach_device(conf, persistent=True, live=live)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/guest.py", line 304, in attach_device
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]     device_xml = conf.to_xml()
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/config.py", line 77, in to_xml
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]     root = self.format_dom()
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/config.py", line 765, in format_dom
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]     uuid=self.auth_secret_uuid))
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 2998, in lxml.etree.Element (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:80607)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 135, in lxml.etree._makeElement (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:17604)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 123, in lxml.etree._makeElement (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:17452)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 302, in lxml.etree._initNodeAttributes (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:19840)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 316, in lxml.etree._addAttributeToNode (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:20196)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]   File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 1437, in lxml.etree._utf8 (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:32414)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63] TypeError: Argument must be bytes or unicode, got 'NoneType'
2017-05-12 02:58:01.339 14474 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 6d58f5b7-dbd0-4ae5-9c40-fd902a0d9a63]
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server [req-15a58e2b-017b-4104-b156-d6ddb45727ab ae67e9e8fc51406fb890389fd06e44af 18483cc44c884278b94bf3bb41421175 - - -] Exception during message handling
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/server.py", line 155, in _process_incoming
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     res = self.dispatcher.dispatch(message)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 222, in dispatch
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     return self._do_dispatch(endpoint, method, ctxt, args)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/dispatcher.py", line 192, in _do_dispatch
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     result = func(ctxt, **new_args)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/exception_wrapper.py", line 75, in wrapped
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     function_name, call_dict, binary)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 220, in __exit__
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     self.force_reraise()
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 196, in force_reraise
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/exception_wrapper.py", line 66, in wrapped
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     return f(self, context, *args, **kw)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 216, in decorated_function
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     kwargs['instance'], e, sys.exc_info())
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 220, in __exit__
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     self.force_reraise()
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 196, in force_reraise
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 204, in decorated_function
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     return function(self, context, *args, **kwargs)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 4778, in attach_volume
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     do_attach_volume(context, instance, driver_bdm)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_concurrency/lockutils.py", line 274, in inner
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     return f(*args, **kwargs)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 4776, in do_attach_volume
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     bdm.destroy()
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 220, in __exit__
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     self.force_reraise()
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 196, in force_reraise
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 4773, in do_attach_volume
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     return self._attach_volume(context, instance, driver_bdm)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 4796, in _attach_volume
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     self.volume_api.unreserve_volume(context, bdm.volume_id)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 220, in __exit__
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     self.force_reraise()
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 196, in force_reraise
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 4788, in _attach_volume
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     do_check_attach=False, do_driver_attach=True)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/block_device.py", line 48, in wrapped
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     ret_val = method(obj, context, *args, **kwargs)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/block_device.py", line 282, in attach
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     connector)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 220, in __exit__
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     self.force_reraise()
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 196, in force_reraise
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/block_device.py", line 273, in attach
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     device_type=self['device_type'], encryption=encryption)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 1243, in attach_volume
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     self._disconnect_volume(connection_info, disk_dev)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 220, in __exit__
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     self.force_reraise()
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 196, in force_reraise
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 1232, in attach_volume
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     guest.attach_device(conf, persistent=True, live=live)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/guest.py", line 304, in attach_device
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     device_xml = conf.to_xml()
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/config.py", line 77, in to_xml
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     root = self.format_dom()
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/config.py", line 765, in format_dom
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server     uuid=self.auth_secret_uuid))
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 2998, in lxml.etree.Element (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:80607)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 135, in lxml.etree._makeElement (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:17604)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 123, in lxml.etree._makeElement (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:17452)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 302, in lxml.etree._initNodeAttributes (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:19840)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 316, in lxml.etree._addAttributeToNode (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:20196)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server   File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 1437, in lxml.etree._utf8 (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:32414)
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server TypeError: Argument must be bytes or unicode, got 'NoneType'
2017-05-12 02:58:01.659 14474 ERROR oslo_messaging.rpc.server
```

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue. .??

Comment: @MohanSanagapalli Canonical people said there was a bug in cinder-ceph charm. I think they already fixed it recently. see [this link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/charm-cinder-ceph/+bug/1711642)

Comment: Thanks man ..!! I tried a lot of workarounds nothing worked. I raised a bug yesterday waiting for their reply . I dont think dey have fixed it .I installed from Autopilot last week

https://bugs.launchpad.net/landscape/+bug/1717139

Comment: @MohanSanagapalli, they do not support Autopilot anymore. In latest conjure-up version, there are only two options everytime you want to deploy Openstack which are Openstack NovaLXD and Openstack NovaKVM, look at this https://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/build-openstack. The latest conjure-up will deploy Openstack Pike, and they have fixed bug in cinder-ceph charm.

Comment: cool Thanks man, this one worked perfectly. Didn't face any volume issue this time.

Answer (score 1):

When you launch instance -- in Source tab --- Select "No" to Create new volume. You should be able to Launch an Instance.This is the work around to launch instance.

I am having same issue when try to attach volume thru CLI or Horizon Dashboard.

$ openstack server add volume 24cf0c37-da44-4765-810c-569a64rfq5b0 ae6c0a48-09e4-411e-958a-60f3mrau1120 --device /dev/vdb $
$

With no error.
When I check the server, there is no volume attached to it.

Thanks ,
MRAU

Comment: exactly same error , I tried all this stuff just like you and obtained same results . Were you able to fix the issue...??